# Customized recv buffer

Tags: c, buffer, recv

I'm trying to fill the begin of input_buffer with some values and write the recived data informations just after these extra vales. I want also to remove '\0' from `extraP` (in input_buffer) and start at this place with filling the input_buffer with received data.
This is what I tried:

```
size_t mysize = 0;

for (;;) {
  bytes_received = recv ( socket_handle , input_buffer+mysize , MAXLENGTH, 0 ) ;
  //extraP is a pointer to string with '\0' at the end.
  *input_buffer = *extraP;
  // i want to remove '\0' and write received data (from recv) 
  // directly after letters from extraP
  mysize = strlen(extraP);
}
```

Maybe someone could correct me.

Comment: Without the whole code I can't be sure but this part `*input_buffer = *extraP` looks wrong. Assuming `extraP` is of type `char*` you are writing the first byte of `extraP` to the byte pointed by `input_buffer`. Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: No, I want to write the whole string to the begin of the input_buffer and start to fill the input_buffer at the location where the string from extraP ended (at '\0'). Do I need to use memcpy for that?

Comment: Yes, you can't copy strings the way you did. You need `memcpy` for that.

Comment: In fact, since it is a string with a '\0' at the end, `strcpy` is a better choice.